# Show cutomize message in Django Admin on delete of a record

Tags: django, django-admin

I am trying to change the default error message of django admin to my own message app that should display like a normal message system
here is my model for the app

```
class Role(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
     slug = models.SlugField(null=True, unique=True, blank=False)
     def __str__(self):
          return self.name
```

in on other model this model become the forighn key. here is the second model

```
class LearningPath(models.Model):
    Path_Name = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    Role = models.ForeignKey(Role, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
```

after that, I have created some roles and then some Learning Paths.

the issue is that I when I delete any of Role that is used inside any of Learning Path it shows me the below error
[image]

what I want is to show the error message in a normal message app as the normal alert div appear. I have tried to write some code in admin.py but it's not working.
here is admin.py code

```
class RoleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('name',)
    prepopulated_fields = {'slug': ('name',)}
    list_per_page = 20
    def delete_model(self, request, obj):
        try:
            obj.delete()
        except IntegrityError:
            messages.error(request, 'This object can not be deleted!')        
admin.site.register(Role, RoleAdmin)
```

Comment: Why don't you use `on_delete=models.PROTECT` or `on_delete=models.RESTRICT` (since Django-3.1)? `DO_NOTHING` will not per se even raise an `IntegrityError` on some databases, it is thus quite "risky": https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.PROTECT

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem will it fix what i want?

Comment: normally you do not even have to write custom code: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_deleted_objects "*protected is a list of strings representing of all the protected related objects that can’t be deleted. The list is displayed in the template.*". But regardless, using `DO_NOTHING` is downright unsafe. Some databases like SQLite do not per se perform validation.

Answer (score 1):

Please don't use [**`on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DO_NOTHING). It relies on the fact that the database will somehow deal with it. But that behavior can be unpredictable. Some database can simply ignore this, other might prevent deleting the objects, or fail *silently*.

It might be better to use [**`PROTECT`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.PROTECT). This means that Django will identify the problem itself, and simply prevent querying the database in the first place to remove the object.

Django admin seems to take this into account as well. As we can read in the [documentation of the **`get_deleted_objects(…)`** method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_deleted_objects):

> (…)
>
> This method must return a 4-tuple of `(deleted_objects,
> model_count, perms_needed, protected)`.
>
> (…)
>
> **`protected`** is a list of strings representing of all the **protected related objects that can’t be deleted**. The list is displayed in the template.

Answer (score 0):

thanks to the Willem Van Onsem comment, my issue got fixed.
i have used on_delete=models.PROTECT into my model and it did work what i was looking for